# Skip button in Run time error dialog in qtp ends the execution

Tags: runtime-error, qtp, hp-uft

I am currently working on an existing framework. In this framework, when any run time error occurs like object not found, and when user clicks on Skip button, the execution ends there.

Can anyone suggest if there is any configuration setting for this to happen? or how is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

Go to File->Settings, Select 'Run', see the setting 'When error occurs during run session'. It will be selected as 'Stop Run'.

Change it to one of the other values depending on your need.